# Knockoutjs not binding to element

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am kind of new to KnockoutJS and trying to use it.

I am having trouble binding the element using knockoutjs. Please see the fiddle below and help in resolving and correcting me.

It is basically not binding the value to the span element.

http://jsfiddle.net/EpyRA/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="taxyear">
    <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                <span>Name:</span><span data-bind="value: ReturnData.Name"></span>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
      var myWeb = myWeb || {};
$(function () {
    (function (myWeb) {
        "use strict";
        var serviceBase = '../Services/Data.asmx/',
    getSvcUrl = function (method) { return serviceBase + method; };
        myWeb.ajaxService = (function () {
            var ajaxGetJson = function (method, jsonIn, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: getSvcUrl(method),
                    type: "GET",
                    data: jsonIn,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (json) {
                        callback(json);
                    }
                });
            },


        ajaxPostJson = function (method, jsonIn, callback) {
            var test = { "Name": "testRaju", "SourceID": "ABCD" };
            //just return data instead of calling for testing
             callback(test);
        };
            return {
                ajaxGetJson: ajaxGetJson,
                ajaxPostJson: ajaxPostJson
            };
        })();
    } (myWeb));
    (function (myWeb) {
        "use strict";
        myWeb.DataService = {
            getReturnData: function (jsonIn, callback) {
                myWeb.ajaxService.ajaxPostJson("GetReturnData", jsonIn, callback);
            }
        };
    } (myWeb));

    //Constructor for a ReturnData object
    myWeb.ReturnData = function () {
        this.Name = ko.observable();
        this.SourceID = ko.observable();

    },

    //View Model
    myWeb.prdviewmodel = (function () {
        var prd = ko.observable();
        loadReturnDataCallback = function (jsonReturnData) {
            alert(jsonReturnData.Name);
           prd = new myWeb.ReturnData()
            .Name(jsonReturnData.Name)
            .SourceID(jsonReturnData.SourceID);

        },
        loadReturnData = function () {
            myWeb.DataService.getReturnData("{'YearID':'" + 22 + "'}", myWeb.prdviewmodel.loadReturnDataCallback);
        };
        //public
        return {
                        loadReturnData: loadReturnData,
            loadReturnDataCallback: loadReturnDataCallback,
            ReturnData: prd

        }
    })();
    //hookup knockout to our viewmodel
    myWeb.prdviewmodel.loadReturnData();
    ko.applyBindings(myWeb.prdviewmodel);
});
```

Thanks in Advance,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of minor issues:

- When binding against a `span`, you would want to use the `text` binding rather than the `value` binding.
- In the AJAX callback, you would want to set the `prd` observable's value by calling it as a function, rather than setting it as a new value.
- In the UI, you can make use of the `with` binding to ensure that it does not try to bind to a property of the observable, before it has been loaded.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Bdz5a/

Comment: Thank you, I should have checked it. Thanks a lot.